# Como criar mensagens automáticas pelo bot do discord com atualizações constantes? (api python)

Tags: python, api, automatização

```
import discord
import TOKEN_value
import memes

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = TOKEN_value.token()

memes_ON = False


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT HAS BEEN CONNECTED.')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global memes_ON
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!memes'):
        memes_ON = True
        await message.channel.send('Now I gonna send memes for you!')

    if memes_ON:
        meme = memes.memes_search()
        if meme != 'no memes here':
            await message.channel.send(meme)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

A função memes_search() me retorna um link de algum meme do imgur, mas nunca é um link repetido, ou seja, nem sempre tem algo novo para mandar, e nesse caso ele retorna a string 'no memes here'.

A função token() apenas me retorna meu token

O que eu gostaria de fazer é que toda vez que tivesse algum link novo ele fosse mandado para o chat automaticamente no local que foi digitado !memes, porém ele para de rodar caso não haja novos links e só volta caso alguém mande mensagem no servidor. A única forma que fez ele funcionar foi mandar mensagens infinitamente mesmo que não sejam links, caso contrário ele para de rodar. já tentei várias coisas e nenhuma funciona. O que preciso é que a função não pare de rodar e continue fazendo a verificação "if memes_ON", já tentei printar alguns valores e vi que a partir do momento que não é devolvido um link ele roda a função duas vezes e para até ter novas mensagens no server.

Answer (score -2):

Não conheço bem a API do discord.py, mas talvez possa ser implementado dessa maneira:

1. Criar uma lista (ou um conjunto) que armazenará todos os canais nos quais serão enviados memes:

```py
channels = set()
```

2. Quando um canal enviar a mensagem "!memes", adicionar o ID do canal em `channels`:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!memes'):
        await message.channel.send('Now I gonna send memes for you!')
        channels.add(message.channel.id)
```

3. Quando um canal enviar a mensagem "!stopmemes", por exemplo, remover o ID do canal de `channels`:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!memes'):
        await message.channel.send('Now I gonna send memes for you!')
        channels.add(message.channel.id)

    elif message.content.lower().startswith('!stopmemes'):
        await message.channel.send('Now I gonna stop sending memes for you!')
        channels.discard(message.channel.id)
```

4. Criar uma corrotina que rodará infinitamente, enviando memes para os canais em `channels`:

```
async def meme_loop():
    while True:
        meme = memes.memes_search()
        if meme == "no memes here":
            continue
  
        for channel_id in channels:
            channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
            await channel.send(meme)
```

5. Rodar o código do discord junto com o código dos memes:

```py
# Substitua
#
# client.run(TOKEN)
#
# por
 
import asyncio
await asyncio.gather(client.start(TOKEN), meme_loop())
```

Comment: o await só roda se estiver dentro de uma função async. Tentei escrever asyncio.gather(client.run(TOKEN), meme_loop()) e funciona normal o bot mas a função de mandar os memes não

Comment: @Obb Você poderia adicionar `print`s dentro da função `meme_loop` 1) antes do *while*, para ver se a função está sendo executada; e 2) antes do *for*, para ver qual o resultado da variável `meme` em cada iteração? Talvez nenhum meme esteja sendo enviado por `memes.memes_search()`.

Comment: consegui, amigo. Muito obrigado! fiz um loop dentro da função principal e mais algumas alterações.